# How to get and set the current zoom of webview on android api < 11

Tags: javascript, android, webview, zooming

There is a way to get the current zoom and hold it when the view is reload using api 9? Everything i have found works only for api 11+.

I'm using the code

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

I can do it using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Well...the solution i found was:

```
current_zoom = webView.getScale() * 100;
zoom = Math.round(zoom_x);
webView.setInitialScale(zoom);
```

That hold the scale when i reload the data.